# Maps OSM for iOS (xcode)

Tags: ios

There is a project. Uses online and offline maps. Tiles from openstreetmap.org

Online map - used MapKit, over OSM tiles.

Offline maps- used MapBox, which is connected to the file * .mbtiles

The problem is the map display. The text on the card is not readable. (see screenshots).

Need Help- properly displaying tiles to read the text (both on the site openstreetmap.org)

thank you!

http://i11.pixs.ru/storage/8/0/1/imgojpeg_4171497_16720801.jpg

Answer (score 0):

Can you check this please
http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/OSM_in_MapKit
And this topic (topic is in Russian, but it contains code) maybe it will be helpful for you.
http://habrahabr.ru/post/173837/